# trimming a list of pairs with OCaml

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml

I am trying to filter a list of pairs and return a new list containing only the first element of each pair. The input/output should go like this:

```
input = [('A', 3); ('B', 2); ('D', 1)]

output = ['A'; 'B'; 'D']
```

The code i have so far is this:

```
let rec trimList l = function
| [] -> []
| head::tail -> let l' = [fst head] @ trimList List.tl l;;
```

but i get the following error:

```
Line 3, characters 59-61:
3 |     | head::tail -> let l' = [fst (head)] @ trimList List.tl l;;
                                                           ^^
Error: Syntax error
```

I don't know why this isn't working. I know this is very simple, but i am new to OCaml.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax problem is caused by the fact that you have `let` with no corresponding `in`.

A let expression looks like this:

```
let v = expr1 in expr2
```

In essence this establishes a local variable `v` with value `expr1` and has the value of `expr2` (which will probably contain instances of the variable `v`).

You are missing the `in` part of the let expression.

As another comment, if you define a function like this:

```
let f l = function ...
```

You are defining a function of *two* parameters. There is an implicit parameter defined by the `function` keyword; the parameter is matched against the following patterns.

Most likely you want to remove the `l` from you function definition.

There are a few other problems with your code, but I hope this helps to make progress.

Comment: I think the "let" is a mistake though. The code makes more sense with `| head::tail -> [fst (head)] @ trimList (List.tl l)`. In which case I would point towards reading up on `::` and that the pattern matching already bound `tail` so there is no need to `List.tl l`.